# How to create PHP search for product name or product designer?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made a simple PHP search functionality, it can search for the `product_name` but I wanna add another functionality so that it will be able to search either from `product_name` **OR** `product_designer`.

**Search Function**

```
function search($dbh, $word){

$query = "SELECT
product.product_name,
product.product_color,
product.year_released,
product.product_price,
product.product_image,
product.product_id,
product.product_desc,
product.product_designer,
type.name as type
FROM
product
JOIN type USING(typpe_id)
WHERE
product.product_name LIKE :word";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

$stmt->bindValue(':word', '%'.$word.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();

// fetch one product
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

**Function Call**

```
if(!empty($_GET['word'])) {
    $products = search($dbh, $_GET['word']);
    $title = 'Products like: ' . $_GET['word'];
}
```

Comment: Something like `WHERE
(product.product_name LIKE :word or :word is null) and (product.product_type LIKE :word2 or :word2 is null)`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use **OR** condition:

```
$query = "SELECT
            product.product_name,
            product.product_color,
            product.year_released,
            product.product_price,
            product.product_image,
            product.product_id,
            product.product_desc,
            product.product_designer,
            type.name as type
          FROM
            product
          JOIN type USING(typpe_id)
          WHERE
            product.product_name LIKE :word 
            OR product.product_designer LIKE :word ";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

$stmt->bindValue(':word', '%'.$word.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();

// fetch one product
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Oh, this totally works! Thanks for the answer appreciate it!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You query need to change in where clause ,you have to add `or` and use your desired column name (here it would be `product_designer`)

```
SELECT
product.product_name,
product.product_color,
product.year_released,
product.product_price,
product.product_image,
product.product_id,
product.product_desc,
product.product_designer,
type.name as type
FROM
product
JOIN type on product.typpe_id=type.typpe_id
WHERE
product.product_name LIKE '%variable%' or product_designer like '%variable%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `WHERE` clause with an `OR` condition.
Not a bad idea to wrap your `OR`'d conditions in parentheses so that if you add an `AND` condition later, the `OR` is evaluated first (because of order of operators).

eg:

```
WHERE
(
  product.product_name LIKE :word
  OR
  product.product_type LIKE :word
)
```